# Overloading external type with new property

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a TinyMCE plugin I wrote that "overloads" the tinymce object with a property for the plugin API.

For example, on init, the plugin calls:

```
import * as tinymce from 'tinymce';

tinymce.pluginName = pluginAPI
```

However, typescript complains because `pluginName` is not a valid property on the `tinymce` type.

I've been looking for ways to overload but can't seem to find what works in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth showing full code. It's unclear what `tinymce` is in your code exactly. But let's suppose it's something like this:

import {tinymce} from 'tinymce';

then you can create a `.d.ts` declaration file with extension for that object:

```
declare module "tinymce" {
  export interface tinymce {
    pluginName: string;
  }
}
```

If you're not including files by mask in tsconfig (*.ts) then you'll have to reference that declaration file:

```
/// <reference path="./tinymce.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `import * as tinymce from 'tinymce';`. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: I'm afraid in this case `tinymce` is an ES-module and you can't assign field into it.

Comment: Would it be possible to overload a function then? If I can overload the `editor.addCommand` function to allow non-boolean return types, I can match how some other plugins return their APIs.

Comment: Yes, I believe you can override return type of a function